# how do I convert from the Calendar data type to 'java.sql.Date' or who know a netbeans plugin for date that accepts input in the 'date' data type

Tags: java, sql, date, netbeans

```
Calendar depart = dateChooserCombo1.getSelectedDate();
Calendar arrive = dateChooserCombo2.getSelectedDate();
```

How do I convert `depart` to the date format?

Comment: by "date format" do u mean a String like " Monday 17/5/1990" or a Date instance ?

Comment: @vlatkozelka The question specifically asks about `java.sql.Date` -- see the title.

Comment: Woops ... well usually question details go into the question body , not the title :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `java.sql.Date` is a thin wrapper around a millisecond value. A `Calendar` has a `getTimeInMillis()` method that returns the number of milliseconds since the epoch.

```
Date date = new Date(depart.getTimeInMillis());
```